# Pay With Amazon Open in Popup Window

Tags: javascript, popup, window, payment-gateway, amazon-pay

I am using Pay With Amazon [Express Integration](https://payments.amazon.com/developer/express). In that I have to create custom `Pay With Amazon` button as described [here](https://payments.amazon.com/documentation/express/201747030#201737700):

Everything is working smoothly, however when I click on `Pay With Amazon` button, it opens window in same page. I want that window to open in `popup`.

Is there any way, I can make `Pay With Amazon` button to open `window` in `popup`.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   OffAmazonPayments.Button("AmazonPayButton", app.conf.amazonPaySellerId, {
     type: "hostedPayment",
     hostedParametersProvider: function(done) {
     $.getJSON(app.conf.siteUrl + 'generatePaymentRequestSignature', {
        amount: $("#depositAmount").val() ? $("#depositAmount").val() : 10,
        currencyCode: 'USD',
        sellerNote: "Deposit to App",
        returnURL : window.location.href,
        sellerOrderId : localStorage.getItem("UserAccessToken")
     }, 
    function(data) {
       if(data.status && data.code == 200) {
         done(JSON.parse(data.data));
      } else {
         alert("Service is not available. Please try again later");
      }
    })
  },
 onError: function(errorCode) {
      console.log(errorCode.getErrorCode() + " " + errorCode.getErrorMessage());
 }
});
</script>
```

I wanted to open it in popup, because my app will be embedded by other sites using `iframe`. And when we click on `Pay` button, it opens in same window which is not functioning.

**Note:** There is option available for opening window in Popup, for Buttons generated using Button Generator Utility as said [here](https://amzn.github.io/login-and-pay-with-amazon-sdk-samples/login_and_pay/lpa-login.html), but don't know how it can be done using `hostedPayment` type.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to do that currently since it is a hosted solution. The sample you referenced doesn't use the button generator it uses a standard Login with Amazon integration. A button generated with the button generator is considered a Express integration.

The only way to have a popup experience is to do a custom LPA integration but the Pay button will not work in a iframe.

Comment: Can you give some reference to how can I go ahead with custom LPA?

Comment: I would start with the integration guide found [here](https://payments.amazon.com/documentation). Use the one called "Login and Pay with Amazon". Same place you found the Express integration. There is a step-by-step guide there. I have also written demos with code samples on the GitHub samples page [here](https://amzn.github.io/login-and-pay-with-amazon-sdk-samples/). Specifically the 'Simple Checkout' example.

Comment: Hey @Brent Douglas, thanks for your time. But in my case, amount is dynamic, and I think for this purpose, I have to use hosted solution only. I don't think I can use LPA for dynamic amount. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can use LPA for dynamic. In fact, it's more dynamic and feature rich than Express. It gives you all the control. However, you will need to make all the API calls yourself whereas a hosted solution will do the Authorize and Capture for you. Express is built on top of LPA as an easier way to integrate.

Comment: Hey Brent, I have tried LPA solution as well, but it does not seem to work in iframe (embedded app). So, does amazon restrict the payment to made through iframe or there is some way to make LPA to work in iframe? Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: My original answer stated that it would not work in a iframe :)

Comment: Hey Brent, thanks got it. Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Comment: That's great! Let me know if you need further assistance.